# regex for alphabets in sed for string/sub-string operations

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

I need to perform some operations in a file using sed based on matched keywords, but I am facing issue in differentiating following two:

```
KEYWORD_<alphabets>
KEYWORD_<alphabets>_EXTRAWORD

sed -i '/\<KEYWORD_alphabets\>/d' temp.txt
sed -i '/\<KEYWORD_alphabets_EXTRAWORD\>/d' temp.txt
```

Here using sed, I need to perform different operations, can someone suggest which regex I can put instead of  so that I can fulfill this requirement?

Comment: `sed '/KEYWORD_<alphabets>/d' file` should work, what's the problem?

Comment: As long as alphabets doesn't contain _ it will be fine.

Comment: What should be the regex for KEYWORD_<alphabets> exact match? Because I have KEYWORD_<alphabets>_EXTRAWORD which gets caught if I search for KEYWORD_<alphabets>. Also _ is not there in my <alphabets>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with `<keyword_[a-zA-Z]*_<extra\>`